# how can i add thead and tbody tags in an existing tab with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Hi my tab is generate by an app and i can't add in the html code the  thead and tbody tags.
So i would like add with javascript the tags
actually my code is :
...

```
<table  id="__bookmark_1">
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>adress</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

...
and i would like
...

```
<table  id="__bookmark_1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>adress</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

...

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If it is for styling purposes only it could be sufficient to use the `tr:first-child` pseudo class selector to style the first rows (headdings) only.

Answer (score 0):

hi in fact it to use datatables code
i have founfd the way to

```
var myTable = jQuery("#__bookmark_1");
var thead = myTable.find("thead");
var thRows =  myTable.find("tr:has(th)");

if (thead.length===0){  //if there is no thead element, add one.
    thead = jQuery("<thead></thead>").appendTo(myTable);    
}

var copy = thRows.clone(true).appendTo("thead");
thRows.remove();
```